# android can't set special color using html

Tags: android, html, textcolor

in the string file:

```
<string name="test1">AAAA<font color="#ff0000">BBBB</font></string>
<string name="test2">AAAA<font color="red">BBBB</font></string>
```

in the layout file,I set a TextView like this:

```
android:text="@string/test1"
```

but it did't work!! the "BBBB" not turn to "#ff0000".

when I set the TextView like:

```
android:text="@string/test2"
```

it works.the "BBBB" turn to red.

I want to know how can I set the text with the color that I want;
not just red blue green...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SpannableString for ex:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("hi #xyz how are you.");
ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 3, 8, 0);
```

Comment: maybe it's no possible

Answer (score 0):

Open res directory then open values . Create new `Value resource file` there.
and name it what you want for example : color

Now open color.xml and edit like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="color1">#3254f1</color>
    <color name="color2">#265646</color>
</resources>
```

Now put this line inside your `TextView` tag

```
android:textColor="@color/color1"
```

Comment: This would not work, since OP only wants part of the string colored.

Comment: @1615903 so i think it's not possible via xml or maybe i don't know !

Comment: maybe it can't do that via xml